Is it possible to implement Content-Security-Policy 'hash' (sha256-) header within an Angular app?
I have an Angular app that consumes a .NET 8.0 API.
Following the Content-Security-Policy (CSP) header guidelines for the HASH approach, I should create a hash for each 'inline style' to be executed (in the Angular app) in order to ensure it has no unwanted changes, and return them altogether in the directive 'style-src' of the CSP header.
Check the docs to see how this works: https://content-security-policy.com/hash/
Coming back to Angular...
For the 'nonce' one it seems there is a solution in the brand-new Angular official docs: https://angular.dev/best-practices/security#content-security-policy
But regarding the 'sha-256' I couldn't find the way to do it mainly for two reasons:

Angular generates an unique code that uses for all styles, during runtime
(check screenshot)

Even when I tried creating a hash for each of the output files in the server (i.e. polyfills.js, style.css, etc.) and add them to the Content-Security-Policy header, they won't match since the inline styles are modified during runtime as well
This is the function were it fails over and over again:
(check screenshot)


Is it actually possible to implement this?

you might try using "strict-dynamic", which I think should allow scripts from a trusted source to dynamically create other scripts.  That may flow through to the in-line styles they create?  See here:  https://csp.withgoogle.com/docs/strict-csp.html
